# How do I fix the "auto-reboot" bug on my iPhone X without resetting it to factory?

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, reboot

Here are some backgrounds:

I've got my iPhone X in early 2018. The device model is `MQA92CH/A`. I have NEVER Jailbroken it. I only install apps from the App Store. I have dropped it to the ground for about two or three times but the screen is not very broken. There is a very light crack on the screen which almost could be ignored if you don't watch it carefully. This (dropping it to the ground) happens about 10 months ago.

About 6 months ago, I've got a problem which was a bit indifferent at first: The phone would reboot itself sometimes. That happened when I switching from one app to another. Here is a gif to show how it reboots:

[image: GIF show how the iPhone reboots]

At first, it would only happen 1-2 times a week, and later it would happen 1-2 times a day. Recently, it happens 5-10 times a day. Sometimes even when I'm NOT switching between apps.

What's more annoying is that I often use a map app on my Cap Play when driving. When this happens, I would lose my navigator for around 30-90 seconds, which is extremely dangerous when I'm in an unfamiliar road or on the expressway.

I would always upgrade my iOS version to the latest one. When I'm posting this, the version is `12.2`. The issue keeps happening without having any mitigation from upgrading the iOS version.

I have a lot of apps installed so I prefer not to have everything reset to factory. Thanks for any kind of tips that I could try.

Comment: Backup your phone (if you can), restore to factory settings and use it for a couple days. If the problem persists its hardware in which case go to Apple Store and get new phone.  If it doesn't persist then restore your backup and see if the problem occurs now with the backup on the device.